# Mac Terminal.app shows a phantom '[' before each line

Tags: macos, terminal

I noticed that there's a phantom `[` being prepended to each line I run interactively on OS X 10.11.4's Terminal.app:

[image: phantom square brace]

This seems to happen:

- Independently of my `$PS1`
- On other people's machines (ex, http://twitter.com/andknf/status/735480290626408448/photo/1)
- When I'm SSH'd into other machines
- Independently of the shell (I've tried bash, csh, zsh, and Python)

But it does not happen with iTerm.app or xterm (via XQuartz).

Where's this phantom open square brace coming from?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/what-functionality-do-marks-offer-in-the-el-capitan-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are Terminal's "marks", explained in depth in [this Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209907/10167) (as noted in [rob mayoff's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445341/mac-terminal-app-shows-a-phantom-before-each-line/37448523#comment62392990_37445341)).

Essentially bookmarks that get inserted automatically so that it's easy to scroll between outputs of different commands (particularly handy for large outputs). Try ⌘↑ and ⌘↓ to see what I mean. You can disable the visual indicators by under the **View → Hide Marks** menu item.